# References to a .ods file

Tags: hyperref

How can I create references to a `.ods` file using the command `\href{address}{name}`? Files with the `.pdf` extension work, but others do not.

Comment: What do you mean by "works"?  The link is not opened by some application on some OS?

Comment: Yes, the link does not open unless it is .pdf, occupy open a .ods

Comment: Which application?  Which OS?

Comment: Its kile, linux

Answer (score 2):

Both `\href{run:test.ods}{some text}` and `\href{test.ods}{some text}` work for me (on Ubuntu 11.04 with TeX Live 2011; the second one opens the file in the browser, which then opens LibreOffice).

However, some PDF-viewers (like Evince) completely block this operation for security reasons. Adobe Acrobat asks the user for confirmation.

Comment: No, Evince allows opening such links. In fact, I used Evince a while ago to try opening an `.ods` file as this question states. I found that this works, but _all paths, even with a leading slash, are treated relative to the document directory_. But this is only one PDF viewer's behaviour; a complete answer would cite the PDF specification on what is and what is not allowed.